# Supervisor -- Not picking the PHP mentioned in command (MAC)

Tags: php, macos, supervisord, gearman

I have 2 versions of php installed in my mac, 5.3 and 5.5 .  But i want to run the supervisor command through php 5.3 only. I have mentioned the absolute path of php 5.3 in command node as well but it is still picking up php 5.5 to execute that file. I am using mac OS YOSOMITE.

Here is the workers written in supervisor.conf

```
[program:gearman_worker1]

command=/usr/local/php5-5.3.29-20141019-211753/bin/php path/to/the/file

autostart=true

autorestart=true

stderr_logfile=/var/log/worker1.err.log

stdout_logfile=/var/log/worker1.out.log
```

Comment: That... is... pretty... darn... weird... How exactly are you confirming that?

Comment: When i ran that command in command line it is working find. but when i ran the command using php 5.5 it was giving me the same error which i was getting in worker logs

Comment: And that error is what exactly...?

Comment: there is no error from supervisor ... since i m using call by reference in the worker and it is deprecated in php 5.5 so it is giving me the error for deprecated ..

Comment: Call time pass-by-reference has been *deprecated* since 5.3. You're probably just seeing that. Have you tried any more concrete steps to verify the version, like, I don't know, *echo the version number*‽